# Click on specific button based on name of the class or elements

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I captured the testName by using `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[contains(.,'%s')]" % test_name)`

How can I capture class name based on testName?
I am trying to click on menu-button if it contains specific test name

```
<tr class="row-1">
                <td>testName</td>
                <td>testDes</td>
                <td class="menu">
                    <div class="menu-button">
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one possible XPath expression :

```
//tr[td[contains(.,'testName')]]/td[@class='menu']/div[@class='menu-button']
```

Basically the above XPath locate `tr` element having child `td` value equals `"testName"`, then return the corresponding `div[@class='menu-button']` element.

Comment: I get error not valid expression. I removed next part and just kept `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[td[contains(.,'testName')]")` but I still get same error

Comment: apologies, missing closing square bracket after `td` here : `[td[contains(.,'testName')]]` (the last one was missing). Corrected.